# ssh password authentication: use a graphical prompt?

Tags: ssh, git, authentication

I'm working on an assignment where our work group was given access to a git repository for our submissions, but the server only supports password authentication for students. So, when I use my graphical git client, the password prompt is given on the console. I usually don't start my git client from a console, so is there a way to get ssh to use a graphical prompt for password authentication, and/or store the password for the session, as I'm used from public key authentication?

---

```
OS: Xubuntu 13.04
Git: 1.8.1.2
Client: SmartGit/Hg 4.6.5
```

Comment: You may be able to store the username and password as part of the repository URL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000173/tortoisegit-save-user-authentication-data . Note that the password will be stored in your `.gitconfig` as plain text, so make it a different password from all your other passwords.

Comment: It might be helpful is you added the following to your question: Your Git version, your OS/platform and the name/version of your graphical Git client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of the information I mentioned in my comment above, here are some other possibilities:

- You can set the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable (either in your shell or, better, when launching your git client) to the path of a helper app which will pop up a graphical password dialog (e.g. ssh-askpass, ksshaskpass, gnome-askpass, [ssh-askpass for Mac](https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass), Cocoa dialog, etc)
- You can use the [gitcredentials](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitcredentials.html) feature to store your password temporarily in memory, in a private but unencrypted file on the filesystem or—using a platform-specific, third-party helper such as KDEWallet, GNOME Keyring, Mac OS X keychain or Windows Credential Store.
- Or, you can use [an encrypted .netrc file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github/18362082#18362082)

I haven't done the latter but apparently that sounds like the most secure way to go about it, assuming you're running the requisite Git version.

Comment: I installed ssh-askpass as a first step, and it easily works out of the box thanks! At a later time, I'll look into gnome keyring integration, as that's what seems to be used in xubuntu. thanks!